# How to have different URL for each Model instance in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, routes

I was curious that how we can create different URLs for each of the model instances.

*for e.g.*

If I have a model **School** which has many associated models with it like **departments, classes, students etc.**  Now what I want is that whenever User registers a new school, it should have its own URL. [ ***New School form ask users for URL and name of the school***]

*e.g.*

www.school1.com/classes/1

OR

www.school2.com/students/2

Comment: You can use different subdomain for multiple users like, school1.golbalschool.com, instead of separate domain

Comment: I know that, but what I want is to use different URLs not subdomains!

Comment: Do you know, you have to purchase domain for every school ? are you aware about that ?

Comment: of course .. ..

Answer (score 1):

Doing custom domains will be a bit difficult as you'll need to manage the domains and DNS manually. However, it is possible. You would setup multiple domains, and point them all to your application. Then, in your controller you would check which School matches the `request.host`.

An easier solution is setting up each School with a subdomain. This won't require custom configuration and is outlined very well in this article: https://mythoughts.io/managing-dynamic-domains-with-rails-b6ab1040dc8c.

I hope this helps answer your question,

Ben

---

**Update to provide specific implementation details:**

On your `School` object, I would add a `domain` attribute of type string. This should be validated for both uniqueness and presence:

```
# Within School.rb:
validates :domain, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

Next, within your ApplicationController, implement a `before_action` lookup to find the School based on the requesting URL. This will be in the format school1.com or school2.com. Note, using the `!` will automatically raise a 404 error if the School isn't found.

```
before_action :find_school

private

def find_school
  @school = School.find_by_domain!(request.host)
end
```

To test this locally, you can edit your hosts file using the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

Add the following lines:

```
127.0.0.1 school1.com
127.0.0.1 school2.com
```

You can then access your appliation via your web browser using school1.com:3000 and school2.com:3000. (You need to use port 3000 as this is the port your rails application will be using by default).

Comment: should I use  **resolv**  ?

Comment: What's resolv? Can you please share a link to clarify.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the clarification. I'll amend my answer to provide more detail on how i'd implement this.

Comment: @nnd if this answers your question i'd really appreciate it if you mark the answer as correct!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180193/discussion-between-ben-toogood-and-nnd).

Comment: @nnd Hey, if this answer helped, I'd really appreciate if you marked it as correct! Thanks in advance 